# Spring + JPA: object does not get fetched from the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am implementing an online shop. I have the following code for saving an order:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<Order, Integer> implements OrderService {

    @Inject
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveOrder(Order order) {
        this.updateItemsAccordingToOrderedQuantities(order);
        repository.save(order);
    }

    private void updateItemsAccordingToOrderedQuantities(Order order) {
        List<OrderedItem> orderedItems = order.getOrderedItems();
        for (OrderedItem orderedItem : orderedItems) {
            // fetch from database
            Item item = itemRepository.findOne(orderedItem.getItem().getId()); 

            item.reduceWeightInColdStoreBy(orderedItem.getWeight());
            itemRepository.update(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Before actually saving the order I update the "weight" property of each item (some quantity gets sold with this order, so there is less left).

`OrderedItem` objects hold the reference to `Item`, but I want to fetch the fresh `Item` from the database (to additionally check there is enough on sale, in case `Item` table in database changed and UI didn't update before user submitted order). `findOne` method I am calling for this purpose is implemented as follows:

```
@Repository
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T findOne(ID id) {
        return em.find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

After the call `item` is not `null`, but it is not fetched from the database: I have EclipseLink logging turned on, at "FINEST" level, and there is no `SELECT` query.

I thought that it is because EclipseLink has this `item` in its persistence context, so it doesn't execute the query. So I've tried adding `em.clear()` before `return` in `findOne` method implementation, but it didn't help.

How do I actually get the fresh `item` from the database?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I've tried querying explicitly in my `findOne` method, like so:

```
    @Override
    public T findOne(ID id) {
        T result = null;
        try {
            TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " e", entityClass);
            result = query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This way I get the exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: ftcApp.model.Order@cf616dce`. I have no idea why, because I'm not doing `persist`.

Comment: It is nice idea to build online shop using Spring. I want to do it too. Can you recommend any useful sources as starting point for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find method will return the copy that exists in the persistence context rather than querying the database a second time.  You can call the [refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)) method of the entity manager in order to ensure the copy in the persistence context has the latest values from the database:

Comment: Just tried this. The `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown: "Can not refresh not managed object: ftcApp.model.Item@5dadd2e0."

Comment: Did you try em.refresh(em.find(entityClass, id)) ?  Refresh will only work if the object is not detached from the persistence context (which will happen if you call em.clear()).  However, executing the em.find first will give you a copy of the object from the persistence context which you can then refresh.  Alternatively, you can re-attach the detached entity with em.merge().